# Не реляционная БД по большому количеству xml документов?

Tags: база-данных, xml

Существует достаточно большое хранилище с xml документами. Структура у них примерно одинаковая. Меня интересует около 10 значений внутри этих документов, по которым мне необходимо провести статистику и иногда получать сами значения. Существует ли не реляционная база данных, которая может решить эту проблему?

Comment: Напишите свою. А так в Eclipse Platform есть EMF модели, которые по умолчанию сохраняются в XML, но там свои заморочки. Вряд ли вы осилите Eclipse Platform

Comment: Просто загуглите xml database

Comment: Некоторые реляционные СУБД (например, MS Sql Server) имеют возможность делать индексы по содержимому xml-столбцов, так что выборка будет чрезвычайно эффективна.